# Category Image Not Showing on frontend in magento2

Tags: magento2, category-image

I Am Using Below Code
When i Debug by `Zend_Debug::dump($sub_category->getData())`
Then image showing 'null' value.
Image uploaded in admin
`array(30) {
  ["entity_id"] => string(2) "88"
  ["attribute_set_id"] => string(2) "11"
  ["parent_id"] => string(2) "39"
  ["created_at"] => string(19) "2018-10-31 13:26:40"
  ["updated_at"] => string(19) "2019-05-25 06:42:17"
  ["path"] => string(9) "1/2/39/88"
  ["position"] => string(1) "1"
  ["level"] => string(1) "3"
  ["children_count"] => string(1) "4"
  ["description"] => NULL
  ["custom_layout_update"] => NULL
  ["is_active"] => string(1) "1"
  ["landing_page"] => NULL
  ["is_anchor"] => string(1) "1"
  ["include_in_menu"] => string(1) "1"
  ["custom_use_parent_settings"] => string(1) "0"
  ["custom_apply_to_products"] => string(1) "0"
  ["name"] => string(6) "Aprons"
  ["url_key"] => string(6) "aprons"
  ["image"] => NULL
  ["meta_title"] => string(20) "Aprons for All Needs"
  ["display_mode"] => string(17) "PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE"
  ["custom_design"] => NULL
  ["page_layout"] => NULL
  ["thumbnail"] => string(10) "subcat2.jpg"
  ["custom_design_from"] => NULL
  ["custom_design_to"] => NULL
}`

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
$subcats = $category->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<?php foreach ($subcats as $subcat) { 
$sub_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId()); 
?>
<img src="<?php echo $sub_category->getImageUrl() ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: $sub_category->getImageUrl() Showing "UNKNOWN"  in img src

Comment: Do other values come through such as ```$sub_category->getName()```

Answer (score 1):

`image` is store view scope attribute means you can set the image  store view wise.

Change your scope to your Store view from **All Store Views** and check this `Image` field value.

[image]
and ***it image is not exits then it means your code giving the right value. So, in that case, you need to upload image for this store view***.